Docker and host IP migration times out on Postgres import
I have a host machine running a postgresql docker container listening and exposing port 5432 on the host. I had a set of scripts that upload a large set of records from a CSV using PySpark and psycopg2 into the postgres container. When I modified the hosts IP address from 192.168.1.0/24 range to 10.0.0.1/24 range the import scripts runs until 28,038 records and then times out. I've created a new postgresql container and the same thing happens. I also destroyed the bridge network ls-network that was attached to the container and this behavior still happens.
Any thoughts on where I could troubleshoot this issue? Other than destroying the network and re-creating it, I have no other thoughts on why this behavior is occurring. (FYI: the same scripts and data run perfectly fine on an EC2 instance, and were working correctly prior to the IP migration of the host).

PostgreSQL has a statement_timeout setting that defines how long a query is allowed to run before it's canceled. If the import process is hitting this timeout, it could be causing the connection to drop.
Check the current setting with:
SHOW statement_timeout;

You can increase this value (in milliseconds) or set it to 0 (no timeout)
Autocommit Mode: If you're doing large transactions, you might also want to enable autocommit to prevent psycopg2 from trying to handle very large commits at once:
conn.autocommit = True

Consider increasing the memory and CPU limits in your Docker configuration

These are good suggestions, and good information to know. However, it doesn't really point into troubleshooting the fact that the scripts were working at one point and started to cause timeout issues after the Docker hosts IP address changed.
